# how to go back from a previous page

Tags: android

So I want to go back from a previous everytime I press the back button it redirect me to the homepage I would like to know if someone can help me im new to this and here is where I try to implemented in my code.

```
public class DirectoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_directory);

        String url = "http://www.example.com";


        final WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView7);
        WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView7);
        web.loadUrl(url);


        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLightTouchEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public void onBackPressed() {
                if(mWebView.canGoBack())
                {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                }

                else
                {
                    DirectoryActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                return true;
            }
        });
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return;
    }
    super.onBackPressed();
}
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: give me an error

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: When I try to implemented your code it give me the red scribble line